# How do I create a calculated field in a pivot table that simply divides two other columns in the pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have these data in Excel:

[image: example data for pivot table]

I created a pivot table that is supposed to calculate the percent of each state's counties that qualify for a certain government program (this is artificial data, though).

[image: pivot table]

I want to create a third column (field?) in the pivot table that simply divides the second column into the first column to create the percent of counties in the state that qualify. I'm looking for a column that divides the "Count of County ID" column into the "Sum of County Qual." column. In my example, the value for California should be 6 / 7 = 85.7%, and the value for New York should be 3 / 5 = 60%.

I can do this by creating a formula **next** to the pivot table, but then when I filter or otherwise change the pivot table, that will break.

**Is it possible to do this with a calculated field?** Creating a calculated field with `= 'Count of County ID' / 'Sum of County Qualifies?'` or `='County ID' / 'County Qualifies?'` in the formula field throws an unhelpful error.

[image: error message when creating calculated field]

I want to use a calculated field here so that when I filter/sort/etc. the pivot table, the calculated field updates too.

Comment: @Michale A ,,,, it's simple BUT remember while creating PT don't select DATA MODEL option,,,, now tell me how U can do this ,,, select any of the Row of PT ,, form Formula TAB find Pivot Table Analyze,,,, then Field, Item & Sets,,, next Calculated Field,,, insert appropriate data into the Dialogue box & finish with Ok ☺

Comment: @RajeshSinha Could you add an answer that describes what you mean? I did not select Data Model when I created the pivot table (by default, it's not selected), and I'm using Calculated Fields (which seems to be what you're recommending) as I laid out in my question. What is your recommendation/solution that is different from what I already tried?

Comment: ,,, please check my recent post,,,, I've demonstrated that how can you add the Calculated Field to PT without any hassle ☺

Answer (score -1):

**Caveat :**

*This post is addressing the request of the OP through comments above.*

***This is the way you need to procced.***

1. Create Pivot Table using Source data as shown below.

[image]

---

2. Next create Calculated Field, using `Pivot Table Analyze` then `Field, Item & sets.`

---

.
[image]

---

3. Finish with `Ok`.
4. On next screen hit `Yes` for the Dialogue box.

---

5. Now you find the Calculated Field with Pivot Table.

[image]

---

**N.B**

1. `SUM of New` is the Calculated field.
2. You can modify it further.

Comment: Thanks, Rajesh. I'm still confused though. I'm looking for a column that divides the "Count of County ID" column into the "Sum of County Qual." column. In my example, the value for California should be 6 / 7 = 85.7%, and the value for New York should be 3 / 5 = 60%. I'm not sure where your numbers came from, but they aren't what I'm trying to achieve. Your comment, and now your answer, are still showing what I already tried.

Comment: @MichaelA ,,,, for existing example above check the second screen shot,, you get the formula ,,,,  you can flip it. And let me show you that how you are getting `85.7%`,,,, in fact you are simply doing this,,, `=6/7*100`,,, and other is `=3/5*100`,,, BUT the Pivot table works differently,,,  !! If You want to get results in that way ,,,, then better opt another method ,,,, like SUMPRODUCT,,,, and thanks for Down Vote ☺

Comment: 6 divided by 7 is 0.857 (ignoring some of the later decimal points). In your third screenshot, it shows 4.66666667. That number is wrong. That's what I'm talking about. The method you're suggesting is not what I'm looking for because it results in the wrong number.

Comment: @MichaelA ,,, in 3rd screen shot formula is `='County Id' /'County Qual.'`,, ,,,,, **read carefully,,, in comment above,,, I've mentioned that you can flip it** ,,,,, and this is the way the PT calculates,,,, if U want to in your way better use Table & other commands !!